# Unity add force to ragdoll and stability

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, ragdoll

Sorry for my bad english. I want to add force to ragdoll like this:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, playerCamera.transform.forward, out hit, fireRange))
{
    if (hit.collider.tag == "Ragdoll")
    {
        hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<ForcePush>().OnRayPush(this.transform.position, hit.point, 6000f);
    }
}


public void OnRayPush(Vector3 firePos, Vector3 hitPos, float pushForce)
{

    Vector3 incomeVector = ((hitPos) - (firePos));

    incomeVector = incomeVector.normalized;

    rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition((incomeVector) * pushForce, hitPos);

}
```

When I play ragdoll is distorted like in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I don't know the reason. Is force too strong?

But i want to throw strongly. How can i fix this stability problem ?

Please help.

Thanks